# Waiting for end of at least one job in bash

Tags: bash

let's consider a following snippet:

```
for ((i = 1 ; i <= $N ; i++)); do
  sleep 1000 &
done
```

How to wait for end of at least one subprocess? And then, exit all of them. Is it possible?

Comment: Simple with **GNU Parallel**, use `parallel --halt now,success=1`

Answer (score 2):

Use `wait -n` to wait for at least one job to finish.

To kill all the remaining jobs, you can use

```
jobs -p | xargs kill
```

Comment: what `id` should I pass to `wait -n` ?